How to get out of tty mode?
I ended up here using "Sudo reboot" . I can switch between ttys 1-6. I tried installing SDDM on tty1 and it now has a login screen and a box to write password but it takes no action after pressing enter.
I've tried "Startx" but it says "A problem has occurred and the system can't recover".
I've also installed Ubuntu-desktop with Aptitude but I don't know what to do next (I'm pretty new to this and just followed similar posts about this so far)
Edit 1: SDDM login screen somehow works now and it opens into a desktop with the folders but no icons, bluetooth, wifi and ONLY after logging in SDDM I can use [ctrl+alt+f7] where it leads to a black screen with a blinking line at top right but I can't type anything into it.

Why did you need to do the reboot? It may have something to do with the issue you face now.

I was following a post's commands for no sound coming from the speakers and there it mentioned sudo reboot. I can't link it but if you search "Ubuntu no sound" its the first post that comes up. The commands were mainly of uninstalling and reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio so I doubt if thats the reason

Does this answer your question? Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI

From the post I tried [sudo systemctl start graphical.target] but it doesn't work either.

It may help if you're specific as to what you had installed.  You mention sddm so it reads like Kubuntu, Lubuntu or a Qt5 desktop; but Ubuntu-Desktop runs GNOME thus using the GNOME DM (gdm3) is most efficient. Being unable to login can occur for many reasons (inc. lack of space in $HOME or your user directory; invalid configs & more). The DM should offer you choices found in /usr/share/xsessions but your details are unclear as to what you're actually were running, nor what you've done to your system.
